# UDP recv() API returns 0 when I do SIGINT

Tags: sockets, udp, qnx

I have a simple UDP application, in which I call a blocking `recv()` API in `main()`. I have also installed a `SIGINT` handler, so I can `close()` the socket.

I have created a thread that simply runs an empty `while 1` loop, indefinitely.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in my application (as it was blocked on `recv()`), `recv()` returns `0` with `errno 2`.

Now, when I comment out the thread creation part, the behaviour changes, and now when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, `recv()` returns `-1` with `errno 4`.

The newly introduced thread is just an empty `while 1` loop doing nothing.

What could be the problem here? I don't understand, is it related to signal handling?

Comment: Instead of closing the UDP socket from within the signal handler, I recommend creating a `pipe()` or `socketpair()` at the top of `main()`, and having your main thread `select()` (or `poll()` or whatever) on the receiving side of the pipe (or on one of the two sockets).  Then your signal handler can either close the *other* socket, or alternatively send a byte of data on it, and your main thread can react to that event as appropriate.  That avoids potential race conditions or other undesirable behavior caused by closing a socket that another thread is directly using.

Comment: agree with you, but i wanted to understand the behaviour of recv() based on if I have thread in my application or not.

Comment: Calling system calls inside a signal handler is UB, along with almost everything else you could want to do.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to know about signals and threads is that in a multi-threaded process, it's indeterminate/unpredictable which thread will receive a signal.  The OS just chooses whatever thread-context is convenient, and executes the signal-handler there.

A second thing to know is that when a thread receives a signal, one side-effect is that the system call that thread was blocked in (if any) will immediately return error/`-1`, with `errno` set to `EINTR` (aka 4).  Presumably this was done to allow single-threaded programs to execute code (e.g. to clean up and quit) after the signal was received, rather than to remain blocked indefinitely in a system call.

One more thing to know is that the value of `errno` is only meaningful after an system call has returned `-1`; so if `recv()` returns `0` (which is not considered an error) and you then look at `errno`, the value of `errno` is irrelevant... it's still set to whatever value it was set to by the last system call that errored out, because `recv()` didn't change it.

Put all of those things together, and the only remaining question is why closing the socket causes `recv()` to return 0; however, as I mentioned in my comment, closing a socket that a thread is in the middle of using is considered bad behavior, so it's unlikely that there is any well-defined thing that `recv()` *should* be doing in this situation... the network stack implementers would be perfectly within their rights to have `recv()` block forever, or crash the program, or anything else, in this situation, since the situation shouldn't happen in the first place.

(bonus trivia:  another really fun misbehavior that can be introduced by closing a socket that a thread is using is this:  Say thread A is using socket fd 12, and the signal-handler calls `close()` on that fd... but before thread A even executes or notices that its socket has been closed, thread B executes and *just happens* to call `socket()`, and `socket()` *just happens* to create and return a new socket with fd equal to 12 (which it is free to do, because the old fd-12 was closed so that fd-value is available now for re-use).  Now thread A is using another thread's socket and doesn't even know it... and data meant for user B is being sent to user A.  This took me several weeks to debug, as the fault would only happen very occasionally when the timing was just wrong)